# Apex Tricky JSON Wrapper

Tags: apex, api, json, callout

Working with a fairly nested JSON response and I can't figure out how to access the list variable for a returned response.

Here's the response JSON:

```
  {
  "response":{
    "code": "OK"
    "responses":{
      "response":[{
        "code": "OK"
        "user":{
          "userid": "589"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the JSON2Apex output:

```
public class Response {
        public String code;
        public User user;
    }

    public class User {
        public String userid;
    }

    public Response_Z response;

    public class Response_Z {
        public String code;
        public Responses responses;
    }

    public class Responses {
        public List<Response> response;
    }
```

When I try to figure out how to access the userId, I can get this far:

```
system.debug(responseWrap.response.responses.response);
```

Which outputs something like:

```
Response:[code=OK, user=User:[userid=171264570]])
```

I'm not sure how to extract that ID though. Any ideas? It won't let me go any further, there's no .user after the last .response, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last `response` value is an array (indicated by `[...]`) in the JSON. So:

```
system.debug(responseWrap.response.responses.response[0].user.UserId);
```

should output `589` using your JSON example. But likely you will need code that handles a varying number of array elements:

```
for (Response r : responseWrap.response.responses.response) {
    system.debug(r.user.UserId);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I've been working for 10 hours straight. Thank you for you help! I shouldn't have missed that but I did!

Comment: Hi @bblackinton, Happens to all of us; sometimes we just need a second pair of eyes to solve a problem.